# How to set positions of Image View to the Center of UITableViewCell in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have tableView with Indicator but when i click on button it show smal popwindow image i want that image should be aligned with cell if clicked cell is at the top then popup should show at top if cell clciked is middel then according to that.

Right now i have fixed on screen at one positions.

I want to make like normal ipad app when you press any cell button addtoFave then popup with buttons is alligned with that cell any idea how to get this done.

Here is my current code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"ContentID %@",contentID);

    CustomCell *cell  = (CustomCell *) [tblSimpleTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 312, 105)];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake((cell.frame.size.width/2)-(imgView.frame.size.width/2),  (cell.frame.size.height/2)-(imgView.frame.size.height/2), 312, 105);

    imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"popupj.png"];

    [cell addSubview:imgView];

}
```

but this shows image on cell one not for all when i click when i click on other cell this image is shown on first cell only i want that which cell selected this should be shown to that cell.

Comment: Your question is not clear . put some code or more information .That will help you .

Comment: you want to show popup where ever you click on cell, is it like that?

Comment: @Mital you are right i want like that as you are asking

Comment: check out my answer below. by which you can get x and y co-ordinate and set your popup's x, y co -ordinate as per.

Answer (score 5):

First add this line `myImageView.center = cell.center;` and Add your `myImageView`  in `cell.contentView` also.

**OR**

You can also put this code for display image in center of `UITableViewCell`.

```
myImageView.center = CGPointMake(cell.contentView.bounds.size.width/2,cell.contentView.bounds.size.height/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

// if you want to display any subview on any view in center.. try this.. choose Option 1 from below

**// Option 1:**

```
   UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
   imgView.frame = CGRectMake((cell.frame.size.width/2)-(imgView.frame.size.width/2), (cell.frame.size.height/2)-(imgView.frame.size.height/2), 50, 50);
   [cell addSubview:imgView];
```

or

**// Option 2:**

// in .h

```
int selectedRow;
```

// in .m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == selectedRow)
    {
       UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
       imgView.frame = CGRectMake((cell.frame.size.width/2)-(imgView.frame.size.width/2), (cell.frame.size.height/2)-(imgView.frame.size.height/2), 50, 50);
       imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Select.png"];
       [cell addSubview:imgView];
       [imgView release];
       imgView = nil;
    }
    else
    {
       UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
       imgView.frame = CGRectMake((cell.frame.size.width/2)-(imgView.frame.size.width/2), (cell.frame.size.height/2)-(imgView.frame.size.height/2), 50, 50);
       imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UnSelect.png"];
       [cell addSubview:imgView];
       [imgView release];
       imgView = nil;

    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     selectedRow = indexPath.row;
     [tableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: it just show for one cell when i click i am writing this code in did Select so when cell selected show this on selected cell

Comment: dont write this code in didselect,because if you move your table up or  down the selection part will refresh(means you can't see selected row) .so, apply this code in cellforrow. but you need to apply some logic over there

Comment: how to do this if i write this in cellForRow so it will not work for other so is it possible to add this image to view instead cell at the same positions then it might work

Answer (score 1):

This is how I made my UIImageView centered using a custom UITableViewCell.

Be sure to add this code in the override func layoutSubviews() {} part of your UITableViewCell class.

```
    var cellHeight:CGFloat = 150
    self.imageLogo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 125, 125)
    self.imageLogo.center = CGPoint(x: self.center.x, y: cellHeight / 2)
    self.imageLogo.image = Common.school_crest_image
    self.imageLogo.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.addSubview(self.imageLogo)
```